# How can I keep a Progress database and a MSSQL database in sync

Tags: sql-server, progress-4gl

At the moment I am working on a project to convert our Progress OpenEdge systems to .NET

So the idea is to create all the tables in .NET using Entity Framework. This should be a clean database that is designed from the ground up.

The application is too big to convert everything in one time so there will be a transition process.

What I would like to do is create some kind of hooks to update the data in one database when the other has changed.

## Example

### Progress articles table

```
+--------------+----------------+
| artnr        | INTEGER        |
| artnaam      | CHARACTER      |
| artoms       | CHARACTER      |
| artkl        | CHARACTER      |
+--------------+----------------+
```

### MSSQL articles table

```
+--------------------+----------------+
| Id                 | int            |
| ArticleName        | varchar        |
| ArticleDescription | varchar        |
| ColorId            | int            |
+--------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at Pro2? It's replication from OpenEdge to MSSQL https://www.progress.com/openedge/features/openedge-pro2